# SQL query report

Tags: mysql, database

I'm just starting to learn MySQL. I would like to run a query that would give me the amount sold of each product, weekly.

So far, all I have is:

```
SELECT sku,SUM(qty_ordered) FROM sales_flat_order_item
WHERE created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 122 WEEK AND NOW()
GROUP BY sku
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to `GROUP BY` `WEEK()`

```
SELECT sku, YEAR(created_at), WEEK(created_at) as week_no, SUM(qty_ordered)
FROM sales_flat_order_item
WHERE created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 122 WEEK AND NOW()
GROUP BY sku, YEAR(created_at), WEEK(created_at)
```

OR if you want WEEK first and the sku:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) as year_created, WEEK(created_at) as week_no, sku, SUM(qty_ordered)
FROM sales_flat_order_item
WHERE created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 122 WEEK AND NOW()
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), WEEK(created_at), sku
```

Comment: **Thank you**, works perfect. any idea how i would be able to get it to display the price each product was sold at for that week?

Comment: In a `GROUP BY`, individual prices don't make sense. What you'll want is a n average price with `AVG(price_field) as avg_price` added to the list of fields. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html
Remember to close the question